# What's the Error?

Tags: shell, awk

I'm unable to detect the cause of error.

Please help point me out and it's corrective action. I'm a beginner and so this will be a great help to me.

mapping.txt:

```
test1 hello
test2 world
```

My Sh file:
parameter 1 = hello

```
a= cat mapping.txt | grep $1 | awk '{print$1}'
echo $a

## Extracting Dump name
b=$(ls -ltr  /home/oracle/$a/$1*.dmp | awk '{print $9}' | tail -1)
```

I'm getting test1 as echo, but i'm unable to substitute in /home/oracle/**$a**/$1*.dmp
script

output: ls: /home/oracle//hello*.dmp: No such file or directory

What change should i do to let it substitute as: /home/oracle/test1/hello*.dmp

Comment: `cat mapping.txt | grep $1 | awk '{print$1}'` is more typically written `awk "/$1/"'{ print $1 }' mapping.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error, you can see the variable `a` is not set:

Change your first line from:

```
a= cat mapping.txt | grep $1 | awk '{print$1}'
```

to:

```
a=$(cat mapping.txt | grep $1 | awk '{print$1}')
```

Comment: You are not executing `test1`. You just grep it and use it in your ls command. Not sure how you get that error (which indicates you are running test1 which I don't see in the script).

Comment: Is this anything to do with String Var type ?

Comment: No, it's not related to string type. The problem is not in the part of the script you posted here. It's somewhere else. Can you show the sh file that you execute?

Comment: Its quite a big file :                     
a= $(cat mapping.txt | grep $1 | awk '{print$1}')
echo $a

Comment: Well, I can assure there's no error in the code you posted with the fix I suggested. It'll get the value for `a` and substitute in the lst command and will give `b` if there's a file in :`/home/oracle/test1/hello*.dmp`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17515/discussion-between-kingsindian-and-maulzey)